# Recursive base case for c++ circular linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

This is all hypothetical,

I have a struct as so:

```
struct node
{
    int     data;
    node*   next;
};
```

and a circular linked list with only a head pointer, how would I set up a base case for a recursive function that counts the nodes of the circular list? I don't even know where to begin because everything I brainstorm, I quickly realize wouldn't work, because the last node in the list points right back to head instead of NULL.

Example function:

```
int count(node *head)
{
   int listCount = 0;

   if(base case)
   {
     then return 0;
   }
   else
   {
     calculate listCount
     count(head->next);
   }

   return listCount
}
```

Comment: Can you include actual C++ code and not just some dummy code that won't compile? Linked lists are an extremely common data structure, so if you're unfamiliar with what they are, a primer in some [open courseware](https://www.khanacademy.org) is a good idea.

Comment: I'm dealing with an object file that builds a circular linked list and uses a fixed "head" pointer, and I'm suppose to implement in a seperate cpp file a recursive function for this circular linked list. I can't post code because I don't even know where to begin with a base case for the recursive function. Every option I've entertained results in a infinite recursive call.

Comment: So what I'm really stumped about is this, how do I reach a base case in a recursive function that involves a circular linked  list(the last node points back to head) with only a head pointer.

Comment: is count a member of node? If node is the only state your function knows this is impossible for a circular list by definition.

Comment: Sorry it's a local int variable, let me edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: This is confusing, the function name and the local variable collides.

Comment: Sorry I'll fix that too, wow, I am being confusing.

Comment: A recursive function for a list of indefinite size is a great recipe for a stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, I agree! The list that the object file builds is probably only like 6-10 nodes long, I know this because I can compile the object file and it prints out the list.

Comment: By the way, how did you decide to 'close' the loop while appending nodes?

Comment: Have you considered not using recursion? And what is a "recursive base case"?

Answer (score 1):

you can make the ciruclar linked list into a linear linked list

```
int wrapper_function(node*head)
{
    node*current = head;
    head  = head -> next;
    current -> next = NULL;
    count(head);
    current -> next = head;
    head = current;
    return 0;
}


int count(node *head)
{
   int count = 0;

   if(!head)
   {
   then return 0;
   }
   else
  {
   calculate count
   count(head->next);
  }

   return;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I never even thought about that, is this the only possible way?

Comment: Sorry, I meant with the restriction of having only one function parameter "node *head" and not using iterative methods.

Comment: nice way, even in case if your circular linked list is not allowed to be modified, you may connect the linked list back into circular form :))

Comment: will, another way would be to compare address, if you can use a global(which i dont recommend) to store "head"'s address then just compare the addresses as your base case, if you reach back to head then it means you traversed the whole list

Comment: I think I'll try your posted method, thank you so much!

Comment: lol it's for my lab  and I'm not sure if we can break the circle but I'm going to do it, and hope for the best! This is what I love about CS, hopefully one day I'll be helping others too.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you'll have a starting point of some sort in the linked list (maybe your first pointer or so) lets call it 'root' for example so the class will look like this:

```
class circle_list {
    node *root;

    ...

    public:
    int count(node *head);
};
```

Now you can just iterate from this node with a base case that if you're on the same pointer as the root node you return 0. It'll return for sure in the first iteration so you can pass this problem by a few ways, for example you can send the head (default parameter) as 'nullptr' and check if 'head == nullptr' set the head to root after your base case:

```
int count(node *head = nullptr) {
    if (head == root) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = root;
    }

    return 1 + count(head->next);
}
```

There're many possibilities here of course it's just one of the possible ideas to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have to differentiate:

- empty list, head is nullptr
- we are at the head of the list
- we are in the middle of the list
- we are at the end of the list, i. e. we reached the head *again*

To be able to differentiate, you *need* to keep track of the head! In the given case, it is easier to do the task with simple iteration, so let's start with:

```
unsigned int count(node* head)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
        return 0;
    unsigned int n = 1;
    node* current = head->next; // start at next element!
    while(current != head)      // only way to detect end!
    {
       ++n;
       current = current->next;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Now, if you insist on a recursive function: As we need to keep track of the head, we need two pointers. No way around. But we can provide a separate entry function accepting the head only and then passing both pointers to the actual recursive function:

```
unsigned int count(node* head)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
        return 0;
    return count(head, head->next);
}
unsigned count(node* head, node* current)
{
    if(current == head) // our end condition!
        return 1;
    return 1 + count(head, current->next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some fixed pointer to head and `iterator` points to head:

```
count(node *head, node *iterator, int *numOfElem)
{      

   if(head==iterator)
      return;
   else
     { 
        (*numOfElem)++;
        count(head, iterator->next, numOfElem);
     }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the only function parameters I can use is "node *head".

Comment: In C++ you'll want to pass in a *reference*, not a pointer, to mutable arguments. That isn't necessary here as you could always `return 1 + count(head, iterator->next)` instead and have a regular return type.